# extract the values which match in both columns

Tags: string, r, dataframe

I have data.frame of two columns with different size:

```
type1    type2
user1  user1
user2  user4
user3  user6
user4
```

how to get the matches? that the result would be

```
user1 
user4
```

Answer (score 1):

See `?match` or the similar `?"%in%"`:

```
df$type1[df$type1 %in% df$type2]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the columns in a data.frame must all have the same length (see http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Data-frames.) so I will assume the last entry in your example is just an empty string "".

What you are looking for is the "intersection" of your two columns, i.e., the elements that can be found in both columns. You can use the `intersect` function for that:

```
df <- data.frame(type1 = c("user1", "user2", "user3", "user4"),
                 type2 = c("user1", "user4", "user6", ""))
df
#   type1 type2
# 1 user1 user1
# 2 user2 user4
# 3 user3 user6
# 4 user4      

intersect(df$type1, df$type2)
# [1] "user1" "user4"
```